# Best way to check for confounding variables in Multiple Linear Regression

Tags: multiple-regression, confounding

I have a scenario where I'm trying to look into possible correlations between Blood Sugar Levels (dependent variable) and various factors such as Age, Sex, Smoking, Blood Pressure, etc (independant variables).

I have performed simple Linear Regression on all of my variables and found out that 3 out of 10 independent variables show significant association with Blood Sugar, namely BMI, Drinking, Total Cholesterol (TC).

I now want to check for possible confounders among my variables. And this is where I'm not quite sure how to proceed and how to perform my analysis.

After all of the research I've done on the subject, I believe I can simply perform a Multiple Linear Regression with all of my significant variables and that this can be considered having "adjusted for confounders" (not completely sure if this is correct though). But what if I want to be able to identify which variables are confounding?

Am I correct in thinking I would then have to perform several Multiple Linear Regressions where I test one significant variable with blood pressure, and then each time add a different variable and check whether there is a significant change in the estimate? With the rule of thumb within epidemiology being >10% change, I believe.

But doesn't this mean I would have to do a very great number of Multiple Linear Regressions? E.g. first I would test Blood Sugar with BMI, adding Age to check whether it's confounding. Then Blood Sugar with BMI again, but adding Sex, and so on until I've gone through all variables? Then I would have to do yet another round and test Blood Sugar with Drinking, adding the variables one by one each time again. This would result in so many MLRs that it makes me think I have seriously misunderstood how to check for and identify confounding variables. And to make things worse it feels like each website online says something slightly different regarding confounders, and the more I've tried to search and read, the more confused and unsure I've become.

**Is there any kind of standard or best practice when wanting to identify confounders among a great number of independant variables?** I would appreciate any kind of advice on how to think in a scenario like this, so that I can try to figure something out with my data in R! Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I read through your link, but unfortunately it doesn't quite answer my questions about the analysis. I understand the concept of confounding variables, but I'm simply unsure about how I should go about testing and identifying them with the actual Multiple Regression analysis.

Comment: What I would advocate doing is coming up with your causal diagram: which variables influence others? If $A$ influences $B,$ then you have the edge $A\to B$ in your diagram. Then you use the backdoor path definition of confounders to find them. Any approach that is merely correlation-based will be *inherently unable* to identify confounders, because confounders are a causal quantity, not a merely statistical one.

Comment: I do not see an analysis of the appropriateness of the linear assumption. The variables might be better related in some transformed space, for example logarithms.